# Beautifying URLs in Yii

Tags: yii, url-masking

I have following file structure

[image]

As default the url created for accessing the module content is for example 
`http://127.0.0.1/tmc/user/default/viewMessage`

and for other controller it comes out to be 
`http://127.0.0.1/tmc/user/booking/index`

The problem is I want to write a rule in my `urlManager` so that both controllers remain accessible AND i do not see `default` word in url as in first example.

However if i write following rules I am able to eliminate the `default` word but now other controllers in same module wont work. any help in this regard is appreciated

`'<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:(.*?)>' => '<module>/default/<action>/<id>',
'<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>',`

My current Url Manager is as follow

`'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => array(
                '/' => 'site/index',
                'login' => 'site/login',
                'user' => 'user/default/',
                '<view:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+>/' => 'site/page',
            ),
        ),`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22034-how-to-set-default-controller-for-a-module/) for config settings

Refer this [Link](http://developwithguru.com/change-the-default-controller-of-a-module-in-yii/)

```
//inside protected/modules/admin/AdminModule.php
class AdminModule extends CWebModule
{
  //goes to TaskController instead of DefaultController
  public $defaultController = 'Task';


...
```

Now your Yii application will routes to the “TaskController” if you request

```
   index.php?r=admin
    //same as requesting
    index.php?r=admin/task
```

Comment: Problem is i do not want to change the default controller i want to hide its name from url only